# How to restrict root access to other users/partitions

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, encryption

Setup:
Laptop dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10 or 11 (both are fine for me).

I have the issue where I need to install some anti-virus software as root on Ubuntu. However this software is really invasive and I don't even know what it all monitors.

So I want to restrict the access to only one login for Ubuntu and that on Windows and on other users on Ubuntu this software has no access.

I'm not fully familiar with how access rights work between users/partitions and OS'es. However with just creating a new user the root user has access to everything and can just run the same code for all users and from Ubuntu you can directly access the windows partition so I'm guessing it can monitor things there too.

One thing I can think of is creating 3 partitions which need to be encrypted with LUKS/cryptsetup for the Linux partitions and Bitlocker for the windows partitions and then install Ubuntu twice one for each user so they can be root but don't have access to eachother.

However I was hoping there's a better/easier solution?

If this is the only way, what is the best way to accomplish this,
i.e.
which encryption to use?
What order of steps, first encrypting the partitions or first installing the os and later encrypt?

Comment: Is there any reason to use the anti virus software if you do not trust it?

Comment: @mashuptwice It could be all fine. However it's monitoring all network traffic and sending it back to their servers. I just don't feel comfortable in having all my data of different clients being send to a 3rd party service of 1 of those clients. So I want to isolate the environments. Normally I use different users, but this has to be installed as root user.